# Update sum of Total Amount

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want to update sum of total automatic in sum box.

Automatic update sum of total columns in Sum Box.

How would be this work, Here is My Code.

JS Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/anosim/6WX5Q/5/

Here is HTML:

```
<table id="items">
    <thead>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input3 unit" name="unit_1" type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input class="input3 qty" name="qty_1" type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input class="input3 total" name="total_1" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input3 unit" name="unit_1" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><input class="input3 qty" name="qty_1" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><input class="input3 total" name="total_1" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br clear="both">

<table id="items">
    <thead>
        <th>Sum</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input3 sum" name="sum" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is Jquery:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(e) {
    var val1 = parseInt($(this).val());
    var val2 = parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('td').find('.unit').val());
    var total = val1 * val2;
    if(isNaN(total)) {
        var total = 0;
    }
    $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('.total').val(total);

    // get sum
    $('.sum').val(total);
});
```

Comment: Would be nice to fire an update when the unit amount is changing as well.
`$('.qty,.unit').keyup(function(e)...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added to your fiddle, you can use the .each function to total up the last column

```
$(".total").each(function(index,item){...});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WX5Q/12/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
var sum=0;
$('.total').each(function(index){sum+=( parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0); }) ;
// get total amount
$('.sum').val(sum );
```

[jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cuzpv/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some logic to keep a running total.  Here is a forked fiddle with the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/pAQxc/

```
var runningTotal = 0;
    $('.total').each(function(){
        var tempVal = parseInt($(this).val());

        if(isNaN(tempVal)) {
            tempVal = 0;
        }
       runningTotal = runningTotal + parseInt(tempVal); 
    });

    // get sum
    $('.sum').val(runningTotal);
```